# Azure DevOpsで特定のブランチへのプッシュを禁じてPRは許可したい

Tags: visual-studio, git, azure

### 質問

Azure DevOpsのブランチポリシーの設定で、以下の2点を満たすにはどのように設定すれば良いでしょうか?
- 特定のブランチには直接プッシュできない
- PRの作成は可能
要するに、特定のブランチ(upstream/masterなど)を変更するには必ずPRを介するようにしたいです。

### やったこと

上記の要求を満たしたいリポジトリのブランチポリシーにあるContributeをDenyにして、Bypass policies when completing pull requestsをAllowにする。
→プッシュの禁止はできましたがfork/master->upstream/masterのPRの作成もできなくなりました

### 参考情報

Azure DevOpsのドキュメント
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops
StackOverflowの質問
VSTS - prevent push to master but allow PR merge
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719803/vsts-prevent-push-to-master-but-allow-pr-merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました

「Repos」->「Branches」でpushを禁止したいブランチの「Branch policies ※1」を選択して
「Require a minimum number of reviewers」の人数を1人以上にして、自分が出したPRを承認できるように「Allow requestors to approve their own changes」にチェックを入れました
こうすることで期待の動作になることを確認しました

また今回は試しておりませんが、kkamegawa様が提案されたブランチのロックと組み合わせることで、履歴の変更も含めて、より強固にブランチを保護できると考えております

*Locking is ideal for preventing new changes that might conflict with an important merge or to place a branch into a read-only state. Use branch policies and pull requests with locking if you want to ensure that changes in a branch are reviewed before they are merged and prevent changes in the locked branch.*
[Lock a branch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops) の 「Locking limitations」より

※1 各ブランチの右端にカーソルを合わせた時に出てくる、縦方向三点リーダーをクリックしてポップアップを表示する必要がある

Answer (score 0):

対象のブランチをロックすればいけないでしょうか？

[Lock a branch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops)

Comment: サンプルプロジェクトを作成してブランチをロックしてみましたが、通常通りpushが実行されてしまいました。
私が管理者権限をもっていることや、他に必要な設定を省略しているなどが関係しているでしょうか?

Comment: 通常通りpushができた要因が判明しました。ブランチのロックは「他の」ユーザからの変更を防ぐものであり、私がロックしたブランチに私がpushできるのは仕様でした。質問の背景に記述していないことで恐縮ですが、ブランチ作成者も含めてpushを禁じたいと考えておりました